# Confusion about convergence for the logarithm of a matrix

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, matrix-calculus, absolute-convergence

How can I prove that for a matrix $A$,
$$
\text{log}A = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} \frac{(A-I)^m}{m}
$$
is absolutely convergent if $||A - I|| < 1$? (I'm using the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.)

In Hall's textbook *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*, the following points are made (around section 2.3).

1. For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, the function
   $$
   \text{log}z = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} \frac{(z-1)^m}{m}
   $$
   is defined and holomorphic in a circle of radius 1 about $z=1$.
2. $||(A-I)^m||\le ||A-I||^m$ for $m\ge 1$.

I see that $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} \frac{||A-I||^m}{m}$$ will converge if $||A-I||<1$ due to point 1 but I can't figure out how to bound $||\text{log}A||$ by that series. I tried the triangle inequality:

$$||\text{log}A||\le \sum_{m=1}^\infty ||(-1)^{m+1} \frac{(A-I)^m}{m}||=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{||(A-I)^m||}{m} \le \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{||A-I||^m}{m}$$
But now I've lost the $\text{log}(z)$ form. What simple idea am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up the Wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: You can bound $\frac{1}{m}$ by 1

Comment: @nicrot000 Ah, so in my last line I would have a geometric series that converges when ||A-I|| < 1. But I'm still confused because Hall emphasizes my point 1 above and now I'm not using that. This makes me think there's still something I'm missing about convergence of logA.

Comment: @nicrot000 Also, I did check wiki before posting. Unless I'm missing something, that page doesn't answer my question and in fact just cites the exact theorem in Hall that I'm trying to understand...

Comment: Note that $$
\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left\| {A - I} \right\|^m }}{m}}  =  - \log (1 - \left\| {A - I} \right\|)<\infty,$$ provided $\left\| {A - I} \right\| < 1$. To see this, you take $z=1 - \left\| {A - I} \right\|$ and multiply through by $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gary supplied the missing link I needed; thank you, Gary!

Pick up at the sequence of inequalities in my question:
$$||\text{log}A||\le \sum_{m=1}^\infty ||(-1)^{m+1} \frac{(A-I)^m}{m}||=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{||(A-I)^m||}{m} \le \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{||A-I||^m}{m}.$$

Note that
$$
-\hbox{log}(1-||A-I||) = -\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} \frac{(1- ||A-I|| - 1)^m}{m} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{||A-I||^m}{m}.
$$
Now $z = 1-||A-I||$ is inside a circle of radius 1 centered at 1 so log converges at this point. Therefore, $||\hbox{log}A|| < \infty$ is bounded above and $\hbox{log}A$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: That's another way. To only conclude the (absolute) convergence, the estimate $\frac{1}{m}\le 1$ is sufficient, yielding a geometric series.